# Button Overlay on ListView Hides on MouseMove

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, button, overlay

In the details view of ListView control, I need additional functionality of editing the entry pointed to by the cursor so I simply added a button overlay onto the ListView control.

The following code was intended to show the button on the rightmost part of each cell of the details view of  ListView control when the cursor is on the ListView control.
To determine which cell was hovered, HitTest method was used.

The problem is, the button show correctly only when the cursor is on the rectangle area the button is supposed to show up. In other words, when the cursor is on non-rightmost area of any field, *redraw* occurs in ListView control and erases the button (and the content of the cell). Also, BringToFront method doesn't work.
How to correct this behavior?

```
class DocumentView {
    Button btn = new Button();
    ListView lv; // designer-generated

    public DocumentView(Document doc)
    {
        btn.AutoSize = true;
        btn.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        btn.AutoEllipsis = false;
        btn.Hide();
        this.Controls.Add(btn);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    ListViewItem mouseMoveHitTestItem = null;
    ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem mouseMoveHitTestSubItem = null;
    int iCol_MouseMove = -1;
    int iRow_MouseMove = -1;
    private void lv_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var mousePos = lv.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
        var hitTest = lv.HitTest(mousePos);
        mouseMoveHitTestItem = hitTest.Item;
        mouseMoveHitTestSubItem = hitTest.SubItem;
        if (mouseMoveHitTestItem != null)
        {
            var iCol = hitTest.Item.SubItems.IndexOf(hitTest.SubItem);
            var iRow = hitTest.Item.Index;
            if (iCol != iCol_MouseMove || iRow != iRow_MouseMove)
            { //Reposition button if the cursor moved to a different cell
                var bounds = hitTest.SubItem.Bounds;
                btn.SetBounds(
                    bounds.Right - btn.Width + lv.Left,
                    bounds.Top + lv.Top,
                    bounds.Width, bounds.Height);

                if (!btn.Visible)
                {
                    btn.Show();
                    btn.BringToFront();
                }
                btn.Text = "" + iRow + ", " + iCol; //test hittest row, col calc.
            }                
        }
        btn.BringToFront(); //takes no effect
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missed status update so invalidatation occurred on every MouseMove:

```
                btnAddName.SetBounds(
                    bounds.Right - btnAddName.Width + lvVertices.Left,
                    bounds.Top + lvVertices.Top,
                    bounds.Width, bounds.Height);

                //-->
                iColBtnAdd = iCol;
                iRowBtnAdd = iRow;
                //<--

                if (!btnAddName.Visible)
                {
```

Warnings help. (CS0169)